# "Print" option not showing up in share menu

Tags: chrome-for-android, share-menu, menu, printing

For quite a while now the print option does not show up under the share menu, as if the share action seems to be missing its share action.
After a while of searching with my google-fu, I have been unable to come up with a working solution, with the two things coming up is:
- Check in your share menu - *If it was there then I wouldn't be looking for an answer*
- There isn't any fix - *yet*

**Objectives:**

- Get Print share action working/shown in Google Chrome
- Get Print share action working/shown in any share menu (when applicable)

**(Un-)Usefull Info:**

Android Version: 5.1.1

Device: Samsung xCover3 (SM-G388f)

Chrome version (Stable): 55.0.2883.91

Chrome Flags Enabled(Chrome://flags):

- `#enable-media-document-download-button`
- `#show-saved-copy`
- `#enable-downloads-ui`
- `#offline-pages-sharing`
- `#enable-ntp-download-suggestions`

Imgur Album Illustrating my point: [http://imgur.com/a/cCxza](https://imgur.com/a/cCxza)

I believe the item disappeared front the share menu after rooting. I have then during that time and now reflashed the firmware and rest the device (for reasons not related to this). I can verify that printing works (I can print from Gmail, and the print APK is still enabled/installed.

Hopefully I've given enough of a picture/details to help narrow down the cause of the problem, and hopefully we will be able to get a fix.

Comment: @beeshyams Can't believe I forgot that. I added it.  But this doesn't seem to be a device specific issue when I was searching for a fix/solution.

Comment: Have you checked the Printer setting on Android system settings? (I remember there's something similar like this on Lollipop).

Comment: Yes. I've even downloaded Google cloud to test to see if it would help. It doesn't. I can verify that the print option works and is available on device (have used it in the past on Google Chrome) as Gmail has the print option.  http://imgur.com/a/cCxza

Answer (score 4):

It could be that in Android 10, they changed the print icon and moved its location. They also used the same icon several times over. To be sure it is the correct icon, you'll need to read the text under the icon.

[image: Print option location.]

Comment: This is what happened to me. The print icon no longer looked like a printer and so I didn't see it. I just tried now and there is a printer share button... But it has the chrome icon. Your screenshot is super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure it out.

I just open `chrome://flags` and reset it to defaults as I didn't find anything with the word 'print'.

And, it worked, I am able to print as I could before.

Comment: I've just installed Google Chrome Dev and the Options there so I've moved to using that, and have uninstalled the default chrome to factory default, so unable to test and verify, I'll need another user to verify beforehand​.

Comment: Resetting flags to default worked for me

Comment: My missing icon was caused by Android 10. See the other answer about Android 10.

Answer (score 1):

Try a soft reset. Press & hold the power + volume-down buttons together and hold for 12-15 seconds. The print icon should then reappear in the Chrome menu.

Thanks & shout out to Tim at Mequon, WI, Verizon store.

Answer (score -1):

For my Android phone connection with my HP printer, I just installed the HP Plugin from Google Play Store and it is now shown in the share option. So, simply click the print button, select your printer, and it is working.

Comment: I did/had numerous restarts of the device, this did not bring up the print icon in the chrome menu. Anyways I am unable to test now

Answer (score -1):

You need to check the print spooler (Samsung system app) in app settings. Enable it, if it's disabled.